# Angular 6 - Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined vendor.js

Tags: angular6, .net-core-2.1

I have recently upgraded a .net Core (2.1) / Angular 6 SPA app to the latest versions.  I seemed to have done everything correctly at one point, but I made a change that broke the http (port 5000) app.  I get an error:

```
vendor.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
at vendor.js:1
```

This is the first line of the vendor.js file.  When I run the app using port 5001 (https), everything seems to work fine.  I cannot figure out why there is a difference in the two websites as they are hitting the same code base.

To begin this upgrade, I started with the official dotnet core 2.1 Angular SPA and upgrade angular from 5 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error and fixed it by changing the port number for the App URL in the Project Properties.

Hope this helps, however I'm still not sure what caused the issue.